# Not able to login with LightDM

Tags: unity, 13.10, login, lightdm

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 with Unity desktop. Unfortunately I am not able to log into my desktop. After entering correct password it keeps looping back to login.

Could you please help me to sort out this problem? I need help because I have important data in my laptop and I don't want to reinstall the OS.

This is my `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=unity
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

This is the output of output after `lspci|grep VGA` :-

```
00:02:0 VGA compatible controller: Intel corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c)
```

Comment: What did you do last time you logged in?

Comment: Nothing It works fine when I was last logged in. After that I was unable to login my personal computer.

Comment: Can you select Recovery mode at boot?

Comment: Yes I can select recovery mode.

Comment: @RohanDongre I suggest that it will help those who are trying to answer if you paste your lightdm.conf file which is in /etc/lightdm in http://pastebin.ubuntu.com and provide the link to it in the description of your question. If lightdm.conf is not present in your PC then you must probably paste your /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf file or something else like that.

Comment: @Venki
Lightdm.conf file contains

[SeatDefaults]
user-session=unity
greeter-session=unity-greeter

Comment: @RohanDongre Try editing that to this.... [SeatDefaults] user-session=ubuntu greeter-session=unity-greeter

Comment: @RohanDongre I must add that after editing your lighdm.conf and before rebooting you must stop gdm, start lightdm and reconfigure lightdm too. Then reboot. If problem persists then give details of this file /var/log/lightdm .

Comment: @RohanDongre Sorry for posting a lotta comments...But you must give more details about your hardware. That might also be needed here. Probably give it before you try the lightdm edit.

Comment: @Venki  its my pleasure to help you to sort out my problem. Could you please tell me what type of h/w information you need.
If there is any command by which we can get the h/w information then could you please share with me. Because I am not a expertise linux user.

Comment: @RohanDongre try  "lspci|grep VGA" (without the quotes) and post the output here.. for your knowledge you can try simply lspci to know much more hardware info. ...

Comment: @Venki output after "lspci|grep VGA" command :
00:02:0 VGA compatible controller: Intel corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c)

Comment: @RohanDongre Hmm..so installing your driver for your graphic card may also solve the problem. Anyways, first try the lightdm.conf edit then if it didnt work try installing the driver. Also first stop gdm, start lightdm, reconfigure lightdm and then edit lightdm as above and then reboot. If this is not working then I guess it must be your graphic driver.

Comment: @Venki I tried with your solution by editing lightdm.conf file but still not worked. so I checked log file it says failed during authentication....session stoppped. I can not write all the log file here because it cantains too much texts and I am posting this from another computer.

Comment: @RohanDongre Check this one out... Does that solve your problem? http://askubuntu.com/questions/346738/13-04-lightdm-crashing-black-screen-flashing-cursor

Comment: @RohanDongre Check this one too... This I suppose is exactly your problem... http://askubuntu.com/questions/253376/lightdm-failed-during-authentication

Comment: Have you recently made any changes to your shell setup files? Specifically `.profile`, `.bash_login` or `.bash_profile`?  If you get authentications issues, you probably need to delete your `~/.Xauthority` file.

Comment: @terdon Probably you are right. That is what the link I gave above also suggests...

Comment: @Venki @ terdon  I tried that solution too by entering rm ./Xauthority command then reboot but still not worked.  Could you please tell me which command will help me to install drivers for my graphics card ?

Comment: @RohanDongre To install graphic driver refer to this page: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.4-linux You may even try deleting and reinstalling lightdm. Some say that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am sharing how I make my desktop on. After getting help by peoples who gave to solve my problem which was I facing from few days back, unfortunately they didn't worked for me.

So I thought lets try it by upgrading distro version from 13.10 to 14.04 LTS. and it works for me and now I am able to logged in my desktop.

Thanks to @Venki, @Danatela for helping me to sort out my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Select *Recovery mode* during boot then *Drop to root shell prompt*.

From there, run (I assume *`rohan`* is your login name)

```
mount -o rw,remount /  #remount / filesystem in read-write mode
passwd rohan
```

Then enter your password and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Now you should be able to login.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to Remount filesystem in read-write mode ? could you please tell me step by step because I am not expert user of linux ?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Danatela, I will try this solution and let you know if there is any issue.

Comment: Sorry to say but solution doesn't worked for me. I have tried by changing ownership of .Xauthourity file too and I have installed gdm also but after reconfiguring gdm it shows that gdm is too heavy for my system may be because of my system configuration. My system has 2 gb RAM and intel core2duo processor.

Comment: Try to add new user and login to that user.

Comment: I had create a new user with adduser username command. user was created but after entering password it is not moving further. Stuck at same place.

Comment: @RohanDongre Are you saying you created a new user in the rescue shell that Danatela explained and then tried to log in _on the command line_ using that user and got nothing? Or did you go back to the GUI? Could you please [edit] your question and include all the stuff from the comments? It is very hard to understand what you've done at this point.