# Kubuntu 14.04 login fails after lightdm/ xdm/ lightdm swap

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, startup, lightdm

I am running kubuntu 14.04.

Recently as part of a python development project changed the DM to xdm. Since then I have not been able to get the system to let me back past the login page.

To be precise, if I enter my password it just blacks the screen then presents me with the Login page again.

I can raise a command line and have tried running dpkg-reconfigure lightdm, which seems to have worked, but to no avail.

I have also run apt-get autoremove, apt-get clean etc in order to try and clean the system of any broken packages, redundancies etc. that might be causing problems.

I tried:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

and restarted...same thing

If I try to start the system and then ESC during startup the system seems to be looping over the same block of instructions.

I  have looked at comments for earlier versions of k/Ubuntu but can't find anything that sorts this. Hence the new question.

Suggestions, please? `ls -al $HOME/{.ICE,.X}authority`

gives

```
-rw------- 1 peter peter 29018 SEp 26 12:18 /home/peter/.ICEauthority

-rw-rw-r-- 1 peter root 155 Sep 26 12:18 /home/peter/.Xauthority
```

(After the changes described below)

Comment: Can you log in to one of the CLI virtual terminals (e.g. Ctrl-Alt-F2)? If yes, please run `ls -l $HOME/{.ICE,.X}authority` and add the results to your question.

Comment: OK so I looked here: [lightdm-failed-during-authentication](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253376/lightdm-failed-during-authentication) and changed the.Xauthority owner to user and set chmod to 664 and that seemed to free it up. But is this really the answer or is it a kludge? I don't really understand.

Comment: It is really the answer - your `.Xauthority` file ownership got messed up (probably as a result of using `sudo` to run `startx` at some point) and now you have fixed it. You should change the `group` to `peter` as well.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using Ubuntu since 2006.  From 2005 to 2006 I exclusively used Kubuntu.  Before that tried various other types of linux.  I like the look and feel of Kubuntu, but I didn't like how often it would crash in the most unpredictable ways.  Since then I've tried several KDE programs under Ubuntu, and time and again these KDE applications are visually appealing buggy as hell.  Do yourself a favor, upgrade to the REAL ubuntu.  **KDE? Just say NO!**

Comment: Hmmmm!! ;-) I have been running Ubuntu since 2004 and liked it. Unity was a big issue  for and I reconfigured to get away from there. With the last change of laptop to a quadcore AMD I started getting all sorts of issues and ended up with Kubuntu + Metacity. My choice. I think though that I will probably go back to Ubuntu soon.

Comment: The "question" regarded an INSTABILITY problem and specifically solicited SUGGESTIONS!  Why, of ALL places on a site named for UBUNTU, am I docked points for correctly pointing out that in my experience KUBUNTU and other KDE products are unstable and specifically that the user should upgrade to the REAL ubuntu?  _*PS:*  After posting this I realized that the user had commented and liked my post, which begs the question who is the one docking me points?_

Comment: Actually although the user replied he didn't find it at all helpful. Sorry, but...

Comment: Soo, when you said you will probably go back to Ubuntu soon, you weren't telling the truth?

Comment: This is an old discussion, but I found Kubuntu not to my liking and now run Ubuntu and nothing else. You were right!